# Stopping dllexport functions in .lib from getting exported from a DLL

Tags: visual-c++, dll, static-libraries, dllexport, declspec

I've got a copy of the axtls library that I've compiled into a static library.  I'm linking it into a DLL that I'm building, and some of the axtls functions (`_MD5_Final`, `_MD5_Init` and `_MD5_Update`) seem to be getting exported from my DLL. I'm trying to figure out how to stop that from happening.

My DLL is built with a `.def` file that doesn't list any of these functions. However, they are all declared as `__declspec(dllexport)` in axtls itself so I suspect that is why they're being exported.

I was wondering if there was a way to block export of these functions, using a `.def` file or similar?  My DLL is going to be used as part of a public SDK, so it's not particularly good to be exposing internal functions like this.

I suspect removing the `__declspec(dllexport)` from the definitions in axtls might solve my problem, but I'd rather not go modifying upstream code if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you have a static LIB file and see all it's exported functions in a DLL that uses this LIB file to build, the solution is simple:

Recompile the static LIB project without `__declspec(dllexport)` and then recompile the DLL project.

With a DEF file you cannot do that.

Comment: Was hoping for an alternative, but doesn't look like one is forthcoming so I'll accept this answer.